# How can I leave a private Stack Overflow team?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm a member of a private team on Stack Overflow Teams. I want to leave that team now because it is used for internal issues at my previous employer. I'm not an admin of the team.

I have searched the settings on the web UI, documentation and, of course, Stack Overflow, but cannot find an answer (only for an older version of Teams). How can I leave a private Stack Overflow team?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are not an admin, you are able to remove yourself from the team under Global account settings in Teams.

Go to any Team, select your profile popover menu (the top right corner of the screen), and click on "Account Settings." Once in your Global account settings, click on "Your Teams" listed in the "Access" section on the right. Here should be a list of teams you are a part of. You can then click "Leave Team" button next to the corresponding team, and then accept the confirmation dialogue.

[image: Expanded user profile popover with a green 1 next to the user Icon. A green 2 is next to the "Account Settings" button in the popover.]

[image: Global account settings page on Stack Overflow for Teams, "Your Teams" is selected with a green 3 next to it. A green 4 is next to the "Leave Team" button for the first team on the list "Team 1".]

[image: A confirmation dialogue to leave "Team 1" with a green 5 next to the "Yes, leave this Team" button.]